# How to resolve "cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc" error in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a events page in my Oracle Apex application with data source set to a view created by joining multiple tables. So when a user tries to update an event it fails because the system tries to make update to the view not the actual table. That's why I created a trigger function that updates the actual table instead of the view. But i am still getting an error.

[image]

This is the script for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_update_event
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON v_event
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Event
    SET start_date = :new.start_date,
        end_date = :new.end_date,
        start_time = :new.start_time,
        end_time = :new.end_time,
        description = :new.description
    WHERE event_id = :old.event_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER t_update_event ENABLE
/
```

How can I solve this? Is there something wrong with my code?

If this is of any help, following is the script for the view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_EVENT" ("EVENT_ID", "EVENT_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "START_TIME", "END_TIME", "DESCRIPTION", "FROM_COLLEGE", "FROM_COMMUNITY", "CLUB_NAME") AS 
  SELECT event."EVENT_ID"
  ,event."EVENT_NAME"
  ,event."START_DATE"
  ,event."END_DATE"
  ,event."START_TIME"
  ,event."END_TIME"
  ,event."DESCRIPTION"
  ,CASE WHEN event."FROM_COLLEGE" = 0 THEN 'No'
  WHEN event."FROM_COLLEGE" = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  END AS "From College"
  ,CASE WHEN event."FROM_COMMUNITY" = 0 THEN 'No'
  WHEN event."FROM_COMMUNITY" = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  END AS "From Community"
  ,LISTAGG(club_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY club_name) AS clubs
FROM event
LEFT JOIN (club_event INNER JOIN club ON club_event.club_id = club.club_id)
ON event.event_id = club_event.event_id
GROUP BY event."EVENT_ID"
     ,event."EVENT_NAME"
     ,event."START_DATE"
     ,event."END_DATE"
     ,event."START_TIME"
     ,event."END_TIME"
     ,event."DESCRIPTION"
     ,event."FROM_COLLEGE"
     ,event."FROM_COMMUNITY"
/
```

Thank you.

Comment: In more complex cases like this, you could consider replacing the standard DML process with your own custom PLSQL code, that directly saves to the underlying table(s). That way, you won't need a trigger either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion that might work in your case.  Define the view as:

```
select e.*,  -- you can list out the columns here
       (select LISTAGG(c.club_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.club_name) 
        from club_event ce join
             club c
             on ce.club_id = c.club_id
        where e.event_id = ce.event_id
       ) as clubs
from events;
```

This eliminates the outer aggregation, which might help.

That said, the issue may not be the `instead of` trigger itself.  It might be how it is getting called.  A simple update on the view should work.  Attempts to lock rows for update -- what the error message suggests -- will not.